# Make chapter gray

Tags: color

Good morning, a question: How can I make "Chapter 1" gray?
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{Título}
\author{Mhs}
\date{July 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{\textcolor{gray}{Introduction}}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```